# registyryvalue in wix

Tags: wix

heat.exe is generating registryvalue for some dlls but not for all. why is that?
Do i really need to use these registryvalue? Whats the purpose of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those DLLs are COM DLLs and heat.exe is taking the COM registration information out of them. You can either edit this output manually, or (if you don't require those COM components to be registered on install) just use `-sreg` switch to avoid generating registration info.